# Add "view more" text at end of the label text

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am binding large text with label in xamarin forms. I am using max 3 lines and after that I am truncating the text. Now I want to add "view more" text at the end if text is large and truncated.

So how can I add "view more" text at the end of label text?

Comment: https://xamarincodingtutorial.blogspot.com/2020/02/xamarin-form-read-more-label-custom.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Himmanshu's like, it seem that not worked when you initialization.

You get the result like following screenshot. `View more` text not be displayed.

[image]

I change the following line from `control.customLabel.Text.Split().Length` to `control.customLabel.Text.Count<char>()`, it work as normal.

Here is `CustomLabel.xaml`.

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App25.CustomLabel">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Label x:Name="customLabel"   >
            </Label>
            <Label x:Name="lblReadMore" FontSize="18" FontAttributes="Bold"  >
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
            </Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

Here is `CustomLabel.xaml.cs`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace App25
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class CustomLabel : ContentView
    {
        public CustomLabel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        #region Bindable Property
        public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            propertyName: nameof(TextProperty),
            returnType: typeof(string),
            declaringType: typeof(CustomLabel),
            defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
            propertyChanged: TextPropertyChanged
            );

        public string Text
        {
            get { return (string)base.GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { base.SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }

        //Show the read more label if word length > 100
        private static void TextPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var control = (CustomLabel)bindable;
            if (newValue != null)
            {
                control.lblReadMore.IsVisible = false;
                control.customLabel.Text = (string)newValue;
                if (control.customLabel.Text.Count<char>() > 100)
                {
                    control.ShortTextVisible = true;
                    control.ReadMoreLabel = true;
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion

        public bool ReadMoreLabel { get; set; }
        private bool _shortTextVisible;
        public bool ShortTextVisible
        {
            get => _shortTextVisible;
            set { _shortTextVisible = value; ShortTextPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        //By Default show first 30 words.
        private void ShortTextPropertyChanged()
        {
            if (Text != null)
            {
                if (ShortTextVisible)
                {
                    customLabel.Text = string.Join(" ", Text.Split().Take(25));
                    lblReadMore.Text = "Read More";
                    lblReadMore.IsVisible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    customLabel.Text = Text;
                    lblReadMore.Text = "Read Less";
                }
            }
        }
        private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ShortTextVisible = !ShortTextVisible;
        }
    }
}
```

Use it in the contentpage.

```
        <local:CustomLabel  Text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."    />
```

Here is running GIF.

[image]